# How to stop labels from moving up when navigation bar disappears?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The layout in Xcode:

Output, in an iPhone 5s simulator once the navigation bar is removed:

Initially, at the start of this view, the navigation bar is required, but when I hit the record button, the navigation bar is to disappear, which it does. However, in doing so, it moves the timer labels up with it. How do I stop autolayout from moving the labels up?

Thanks.

Comment: Setting up the `top constraint` with `top layout guide` may work. Please give it a try once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by grouping the elements I wanted (bottom views) into a stacked view, then by setting a constraint to the bottom, whilst leaving a constraint on the top element to the top.

Answer (score -1):

Use Push function to navigate the first page to another and add navigation disappear Function to next page. It will work.

Comment: I've got the navigation bar disappearing fine, this is a constrains problem.

Answer (score -1):

This happens with respect to how you put your auto layout constraints. Put label constraints with respect to **Top layout guide**. If labels are inside another view make sure that view has top constraint with respect to parentview controller toplayout guide. Check with respect to what you have given. If with respect to Navigation Layout is there. You will have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to force the navigation bar to not be hidden. Inside the `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set top layout guide to 64

> Select viewController on which you are using it and make sure "Under top Bars" is ticked as in Picture below

[image]